# I'd like to model some compounds with DFTB, but some elements don't have parameter files in the official site. Is there a workaround?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, density-functional-theory, semi-empirical-method

I was reading a bit about this technique, [Density Functional based Tight binding (DFTB)](https://www.dftb.org/about-dftb/). It's claimed it can provide a speed improvement of several fold when compared to plain [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory), still giving acceptable results. I downloaded one of its free implementations, the [DFTB+ package](https://www.dftbplus.org/), and started to work on their tutorial. The problem is, like a semiempirical method, this technique demands parameters. In DFTB the parameters are downloaded separately, as a series of files for each bonded element pair. The problem is, in the page linked as [the repository](https://www.dftb.org/parameters/download/) for such parameter files, the options listed don't cover every possible element pair in the periodic table. I my case, I'm interested in heavier members of the alkaline earth group, Sr and Ba. But the only elements in this group with parameter files available are Mg and Ca.

So, I wonder if there is a workaround, short of doing the parametrization on my own, what I imagine would probably be a whole research project on itself, and far beyond my league. Perhaps that repository page just doesn't list every Slater-Koster file in existence, ond others may be found somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you try out [xtb](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html) by the Grimme group. It is a state-of-the-art Tight Binding program parameterized for elements up to Radon (already built-in). There is a small caveat: the only precompiled binary they distribute is for Linux (but the program is open source, so you can compile it yourself if you want.)

And yes, it is *really* fast.

Comment: Thank you, Raphaël. The fact it runs on Linux is a plus for me. Ditched Windows for Ubuntu years ago, never looked back.